# Remove 12.04 from dual boot with 13.10

Tags: 12.04, 13.10

When I installed 13.10 on my laptop, for some reason I decided to make it a dual boot with 12.04 LTS. I don't use the older OS any more and I was wondering if I can remove 12.04? or do I have to do a reinstall?

Answer (score 0):

Just format the drive with the older Ubuntu and go to /etc/fstab edit the file to remove the occurence of 12.04 and you are done.